# Flowtype: Subtype relationship with object with optional properties

Tags: javascript, flowtype

What is the typing relationship between `type A` & `type B`?

```
type A = {
  a: string,
}

type B = {
  a: string,
  b?: string, // Same thing as —> "b: void | string"
}

// "-" means contravariant & write only & can accept supertypes
function test<-T: B>(value: T): void {}

declare var foo: A

test(foo)
```

**Flowtype.org** (Try Flow)
https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AQVALygDeiooAhgFygDOKATgJYB2A5gDSIC+y62oAEKESZSjXrN2XcgCMA-BMatOoEKADKFALY4UACxWVaoQCgEAPlAAiWTQBusJgBNQAHzrL2VnsnVWAtFaguhQsJgDGsCyMFHYUzKEooABkoPDMKDhR0GgpoOGhlOHhWBhJtACu2Az8WLSIkBUs4ShMUaCZ9AA8-gAqNILmABRx0BVYNL0AlPaOLsS8iE5Y4dDxOHEMoJCwsDS4fHUoQzuwU0A

According to https://flowtype.org/docs/variance.html#object-types....

> ...the subtyping relationship between objects is derived from the
>   subtyping relationships of their properties.

Since `b?: string` is the same thing as `b: void | string`, does that mean we are comparing two distinct value types (with different properties) with no relationship?

It seems logical to me that `{ a: string }` would be a "supertype" of `{ a: string, b: string }`, since it is a more specific "value type."  ...the same thing would go for `{ a: string }` and `{ a: string, b?: string }`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the typing relationship between type A & type B?

`B` is a subtype of `A`.

You can verify this by typchecking code like this:

```
let b: B = {a:'bar', b:'wibble' };
let a: A = b;
```

> // "-" means contravariant & write only & can accept supertypes
>   function test<-T: B>(value: T): void {}

I think this might be where you are getting confused.

You can't read from a contravariant value, which means it doesn't make very much sense as the argument to a function. And this isn't just an arbitrary restriction: if you *could* use the value, you wouldn't be able to do anything with it because you couldn't make any assumptions about what it is.

When we talk about covariant types, we are usually talking about function arguments. The function which uses that argument can usually just ignore any specialization and therefore deal with any subtype. We specify the variance from the perspective of a value *consumer*, and we're expressing which *providers* are compatible.

A contravariant type is usually a return value. We specify a contravariant return type from the perspective of a *provider*. The **supertype** restriction comes in by saying that any *consumer* of this value must not expect something more specific that we're giving it. For example, specifying a contravariant return type of `Dog` means that I'm going to give you some kind of `Dog`, but you may not assume anything more than that: you can treat it like a `Mammal` or a `HasFur`, but you can't treat it like a `Poodle` or else you're going to have problems, which is what the typechecker prevents here.